# How to determine face shape using Firebase ML kit?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase ML kit in an android application for face detection so far everything is fine but now i just want to detect the face shape(Oval, Square or heart Face shape). I read the documentation but couldn't find anything relating to face shapes. May be i overlooked or may there isn't anything about it. If there is a way please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the documentation of the product doesn't mention the feature you're looking for, then it's most likely that this feature isn't a part of that product.

You could try to derive the shape from the information that ML Kit *does* deliver, for example from the [bounding box](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFace.html#getBoundingBox()), but the information might not be enough for that.

Outside of that, the best way to implement this feature in that case is to [train a custom AutoML model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/train-image-labeler) to detect the face shape.

Comment: Okay, this is a good possibility i'll try to train a custom model. Thank you for your response.